# I can't get rid of this scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have website with a form sliding from the right when you click on a blue button:

As you can probably see, the horizontal scrollbar allows visitors to see the sliding form before and after it becomes active.
That's the problem, I hope someone can help me solve it.

This is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                function positioningForm()
                {
                    $('#insider').css({"right": "-535px"}).show();
                }
                function slideFromRight()
                {
                    $('#insider').animate(
                    {right: "0px"},
                    {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
                }
                function slideToBeginning() {
                    $('#insider').animate(
                    {right: "-535px"},
                    {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
                }

                // Positioning the insider at the time of page loading
                positioningForm();

                var state = 0;
                $('.right_btn').click(function() {
                    if(state == 0) {
                        //do the magic :)
                        slideFromRight();
                        state = 1;
                    } else if( state == 1) {
                        //unroll the magic :)
                        slideToBeginning();
                        state=0;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to css:

`body{overflow-x:hidden;}`

if you don't have an organized block of css, just add style="overflow-x:hidden" to your body tag like so:

`<body style="overflow-x:hidden;">`

solved. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The scroll appears because you are not hiding, but moving the element to the right. It is all about css. Possible solutions are `overflow-x:hidden`[<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) [<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or adding adding a container with `display:none`[<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) [<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the non-button part.

Comment: @IWalkedAway Glad you like it. It is breaking the concept to move this button to the right, and the first that I`m seeing.

Comment: yeah, that's the idea I had but I decided to ask the question before I give it a try :)